# Execute instructions in chef recipes only for Test Kitchen converge action

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I need a way to run parts of chef recipes only in case of converge action in Test Kitchen.

I found a way to do it for ChefSpec:

```
unless defined?(ChefSpec)
  
  cookbook_file "/home/#{node['user']}/script.sh" do
    source 'install.sh'
    owner node['user']
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end

end
```

How I can do it for Kitchen tool?

Answer (score 0):

This requirement has been discussed in detail on a [feature request](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/458) on Github.

There are two ways to do this. One is to define an environment variable such as `TEST_KITCHEN`, then use it in recipe with `if` condition, `only_if` or `not_if` guards.

Below should work:

Set the environment variable:

```sh
export TEST_KITCHEN="1"
```

Run the resource conditionally:

```rb
if ENV['TEST_KITCHEN']
  cookbook_file "/home/#{node['user']}/script.sh" do
    source 'install.sh'
    owner node['user']
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Other way is to use a node attribute, something like `node['test_kitchen']` set to `true` and use it to run actions conditionally.

```rb
  cookbook_file "/home/#{node['user']}/script.sh" do
    source 'install.sh'
    owner node['user']
    mode '0755'
    action :create
    only_if { node['test_kitchen'] }
  end
```